# PHP - Login Logout Technique for Big User DataBase

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am creating a website with login functionality in php. Generally I use "sessions" for storing login user data. I am just afraid if sessions will be safe to use. Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to differ from what you "generally" use on this specific project?

Answer (score 1):

We use a mysql table `userIn`, for handling sessions.
When user logs in, a line inserted to `userIn (userID, sessionID, date, IP)`
And a cookie stored on client with just the sessionID, with this you can

- Delete previous open session of the same user
- Check the IP on every call (if someone grab the sessionID, he cannot communicate in the name of the user)
- You can delete the lines from `userIn` to log out the users by time (eg. 8 hours, or so)

How it works:

- Log in: `INSERT INTO userIn SET userID='', sessionID='', date=NOW(), IP='$REMOTE_ADDR'`
  then set a cookie: `SetCookie("MySession", $sessionID);`
- On every page load: `SELECT * FROM userIn WHERE sessionID='$_COOKIE[MySession]' AND IP='$REMOTE_ADDR'` (and optionally update the date in `userIn`)